# Get DataGrid data from SQLite view

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I'm working on an `WPF` application. It has a couple of `TextBox` fields and an `DataGrid`.
To create the SQLite database (with only one table) I have have done this...

```
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
command.CommandText = "CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL,name VARCHAR(100)...
```

And so on...
Now The query to create view is:

```
command.CommandText = "CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS users_details AS SELECT name,adress...
```

And so on again.
This works flawless, but... I'm stuck on one problem. I want to connect that view "user_details" with my `DataGrid`.
Any guidance or part of solution would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create another `SQLiteCommand` to retrieve the data from the view and then use it as an `ItemsSource` for the `DataGrid`

```
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users_details"

SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
```

Comment: It's giving one error on last line...
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I've changed it to dt.AsDataView()

Comment: Okay...no error but nothing on the data grid...
Here is my XAML code of DataGrid
`<DataGrid  Margin="420,10,30,10" SelectionChanged="user_datagrid" Name="user_view" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />`

Comment: Can't you just do some basic debugging? Do you know how to use a breakpoint? What is in the DataTable?